# How to hardcode a MobX store?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I am working on a React app that uses MobX for state management. While defining a store for some new features I want to initially hardcode the store so I can eliminate a variable from the debugging process. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just create a store with default values: `class Store { @observable value = 5; }; const store = new Store();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing that too, it's a good idea for prototyping and `mobx` makes it absolutely trivial!

```
class State {
  @observable boxes = [
    {
      id: 0,
      backgroundImg: 'img1.png',
      opened: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      backgroundImg: 'img2.png',
      opened: false,
    },
  ]
}
```